# How to pass data from table of record to Modal

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i know this question has been asked a lot, but all solution are not suitable for me.I essentially have a table inside a view that is displayed using a foreach loop in HTML and sqlalchemy ,this spits out the records one by one and appends some 'Action' buttons in the last column ( delete and edit),I just pass the ID in from each record in the foreach loop, then job done.

I'm having a lot of issues with my modal though, it only ever displays the data from the first record when I echo the data in the 'value' field of each input，I'm really stumped on how to make this functionality work (javascriptis not my strongest language), it's possible work without using Ajax and php?
i am using flask, python and sqlalchemy.

I think the issue is that the modal is only created once when the foreach loop starts running, hence why it only ever has the first record data inside the modal, any help to get around this so I can edit each individual record inside the table would be great! Thanks for the help.

my html code

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block title %}
            Admin
        {% endblock %}
        {% block body %}
          <h1> Admin</h1>
          <div class="form-group">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th>usa_order_id</th>
            <th>user_id</th>
            <th>cpu</th>

          </tr>
          {% for usa_order in usa_orders %}
          <tr>
            <th><input class="form-control" name ="usa_order_id" value={{usa_order.usa_order_id}}></th>
            <th><input class="form-control" name ="user_id" value={{usa_order.user_id}}></th>
            <th><input class="form-control" name ="cpu" value={{usa_order.cpu}}></th>

            <th>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Open modal
              </button>
              <!-- The Modal -->
              <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">

                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">

                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input class="form-control" name ="usa_order_id" value=usa_order_id>
                          <input class="form-control" name ="user_id" value=user_id>
                          <input class="form-control" name ="cpu" value=cpu>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
          </div>
            {% endblock %}
```

my flask python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from  model import *
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:xxx@localhost:3306/xxx'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN']=True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route("/admin")
def index():
    usa_order = usa_order.query.all()
    return render_template("admin.html",usa_order = usa_order)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0")
```

my model.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
class usa_order(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "usa_order"
    usa_order_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    cpu = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to give each `Modal` a unique ID, so it wouldn't be always superseded by the `Modal` generated first. Try the following `HTML` instead:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
        {% block title %}
            Admin
        {% endblock %}
        {% block body %}
          <h1> Admin</h1>
          <div class="form-group">
        <table border=1>
          <tr>
            <th>usa_order_id</th>
            <th>user_id</th>
            <th>cpu</th>

          </tr>
          {% for usa_order in usa_orders %}
          <tr>
            <th><input class="form-control" name ="usa_order_id" value={{usa_order.usa_order_id}}></th>
            <th><input class="form-control" name ="user_id" value={{usa_order.user_id}}></th>
            <th><input class="form-control" name ="cpu" value={{usa_order.cpu}}></th>

            <th>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{usa_order.id}}">
                Open modal
              </button>
              <!-- The Modal -->
              <div class="modal" id="myModal{{usa_order.id}}">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">

                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">

                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input class="form-control" name ="usa_order_id" value=usa_order_id>
                          <input class="form-control" name ="user_id" value=user_id>
                          <input class="form-control" name ="cpu" value=cpu>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
          </div>
            {% endblock %}
```

**NOTE**: All i did there is to add the record ID to the `Modal` ID.